# Display acf map field in the front end

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How could I display just the map only on the front end using advance custom fields?

I've checked the documentation and it' doesn't show a way just to display a specific field.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php

```
function my_acf_google_map_api( $api ){

    $api['key'] = 'xxx';

    return $api;

 }

add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api', 'my_acf_google_map_api');
```

This will enable the google maps api.

```
    <?php $location = get_field('location'); if( !empty($location) ):?>
        <div class="acf-map">
            <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Make sure to change **location** int he get_field tot he name of your map field.

This is all documented in the ACF Map page: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/